# Setting IP address in initialDirectory

Tags: c#

I would like to know if it is possible to set InitialDirectory as an IP address followed by the folder path, as I would need to connect to my partner's computer in order to save a file there. The current code is

```
 dlg.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "new_folder2");
```

I have tried doing this

```
dlg.InitialDirectory = @"\\111.11.11.111\c$\UploadedFiles";
```

But it didn't work. Do note that I had input-ed my actual IP in the source code.

Is there a way to be able to add in IP address?

EDIT: I had managed to put in my own IP address, turns out I was using the wrong IP. Now is there any other way to use the IP of another person? I'm trying to save images to my partner's computer.